# While stop Media Recorder getting an error java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

While stop Media Record getting an error like java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.When connected to the webcam to the Android device. But it is working fine wen webcam disconnected.
Can any one help me how to solve this.

Comment: I would like to help you if I can. However, it's really hard to infer what is wrong, given only the error. I suggest posting stack trace from logcat and the particular line of code causing the error. This way, the community can help, or at least guide you.